# Stop Internet Explorer 8 Page From Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

is it possible? basically i have a 'popup' that appears on a page when a user clicks a button, and i can get the page to stop scrolling in most browsers with:

```
body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

but that doesn't work for IE? I have also tried this as a hack:

```
body.style.position = "fixed";
```

that actually works, but it returns the user to the top of the page!

is there a way to do this with only js/css? and not jq?

Comment: Ehm, do you want the page to refrain from scrolling even if the user has scrolled down already?

Comment: @MrLister yes, that is what i'm trying to do. the popup itself needs to be scrolled, so it is very confusing when the page underneath it scrolls with it

Comment: Can you post a small demo perhaps that shows what you're trying to do?  I've never seen `html, body { overflow:hidden }`  not work

Comment: @Kyle here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/jvfvq/      but it seems like jsfiddle doesn't even work on IE8!

Comment: try add body.style.position = "relative" instead of fixed

Comment: @HavenLivell I tried your fiddle in both IETester under IE8 mode, and in IE10 under IE8 render mode.  I cannot reproduce what you're talking about or I don't understand the problem.  When I click the Open Popup! It removes scrollbars from the page and I can't scroll via mouse either..which from what i'm understanding, is the desired behavior?  Or course I can't test with a real IE8

Answer (score 0):

you could set the positioning to fixed and the overflow to scroll. So if the user does scroll the page the pop up stays and you can still scroll the pop up if the length or width exceeds your set proportions. Style it in CSS:

```
#popup
{
margin:auto;
width:600px;
height:300px;
background-color:#666;
position:fixed;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve it'd be much easier if you posted a demo of what you have so far

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left` instead of `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`. It will work for sure. :)